# Unprioritize dashboard from search bar in Tableau Server

Tags: search, tableau-desktop

I recently uploaded a dashboard in Tableau Server and want it to be prioritized over other dashboards with a similar name when a user types in the search bar.

Is there a feature or a quick hack to do so ? I still need the older dashboards to be available though.

Thanks in advance for your answers !